# Past tense - did pay or did paid

Tags: verbs, past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

Please let me know which sentence is correct?

> Upon checking, you are indeed correct. **You did pay** the balance on your credit card. We will refund you the amount in your next pay check.

Or

> Upon checking, you are indeed correct. **You did paid** the balance on your credit card. We will refund you the amount in your next pay check.

Comment: Auxiliary *do* always takes an infinitive complement.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: This feels like one of the most commonly asked questions on ELL - this must be a duplicate...

Comment: @user142781 - It means the first sentence is the correct version.

Comment: @StoneyB: Granted it's non-standard, but even those native speakers who wouldn't dream of actually *saying* it would be perfectly familiar with [He done paid me](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+done+paid+me%22) (or even more well-known, [My man done me wrong](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22my+man+done+me+wrong%22)).

Comment: I think it should be"on checking..."  and not "upon".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Fersher; but *done* is certainly a lexical verb in your second example, and I'd argue that in both we're dealing with a dialect construction so distinct from standard usage that the identification of finite *done* with ordinary *do* is excluded.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple past**: you paid the balance on your credit card.

the use of **emphatic helping verb** = helping verb + notional form of the vert:

- You **did pay** the balance on your credit card.

- He **does speak** English.

- She **does like** to play tennis.

Please note: the emphatic helping verb can be: do/does, did, will or have. [I have not given examples of every use of it].

Comment: Yes, explained well. DO/DOES are auxiliary(supportive) to stress the main verb. It makes main verb V1 form, You don't say. He does speak's' English. Because, there is already 'es' in does. It never be does+verb(s) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is: I did pay my bills. :)

The incorrect one: I did paid my bills. :(

You are using the auxiliary 'do' in the past tense, so there is no need to change the verb pay into past tense.

Answer (score 0):

With *do* you need to use the infinitive (i.e. dictionary version) of the complement verb, in this case "pay". So your first sentence with "**did pay**" is the correct one.

Comment: Yes!!!!!' I got it right ;)

Comment: Note that "did pay" is only useful if you want to be emphatic, like in the example above - in most cases, you'll want to just use the simple past, "**You paid** the correct balance" (and that would also be grammatically correct as an alternative here)

Answer (score 0):

You did pay the balance.

You did paid the balance.

"Pay" is a main verb, and "did" (the past of do and does) is an auxiliary verb.  All these forms of the auxiliary are always used with a an infinitive without to whether you form an interrogative, negative, or emphatic sentence.

So the first sentence that is in the past is grammatical, whereas the second one is not correct. You have used the "did" to give extra force or emphasis to the verb "pay".

Furthermore, you stress do, does, and did when these are used to emphasize a verb.